# Is there a way to include stdio.h but ignore some of the functions therein?

Tags: r, stdio, gcc4.8

Let me preface this question by stating I am pretty much a programming neophyte, and not well-trained in either C or the GNU environment. Also, I really cannot provide a reproducible example, as I haven't written this code, I am just trying to build it. I have taught myself enough to compile some programs, given a good pre-existing makefile, and have compiled R for Windows using Rtools many times.

I have been trying to compile R for Windows (7 64 bit) using GCC 4.8.4 (Rtools still lives in 4.6.3 prerelease, and the link-time optimizations in 4.9 have resurrected [some](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-December/070286.html) [old](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-December/070319.html) [bugs](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-January/070378.html)), and can do so with one problem. In one of the files ([/src/extra/trio/compat.c](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/R/src/extra/trio/compat.c) to be precise) there is both an inclusion of stdio.h and definitions for `sprintf` and `vsprintf`. Therefore, the build crashes with the following error:

```
In file included from compat.c:3:0:
F:/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:553:5: note: previous
definition of 'snprintf' was here
 int snprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char *
__restrict__ __format, ...)
     ^
compat.c:75:5: error: redefinition of 'vsnprintf'
 int vsnprintf(char *buffer, size_t bufferSize, const char *format,
va_list args)
     ^
In file included from compat.c:3:0:
F:/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:543:7: note: previous
definition of 'vsnprintf' was here
   int vsnprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char
* __restrict__ __format, va_list __local_argv)
       ^
../../gnuwin32/MkRules:218: recipe for target 'compat.o' failed
make[4]: *** [compat.o] Error 1
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'rlibs' failed
make[3]: *** [rlibs] Error 1
Makefile:179: recipe for target '../../bin/x64/R.dll' failed
make[2]: *** [../../bin/x64/R.dll] Error 2
Makefile:104: recipe for target 'rbuild' failed
make[1]: *** [rbuild] Error 2
Makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The lines in compat.c are those in 65–79:

```
int snprintf(char *buffer, size_t max, const char *format, ...)
{
    int res;
    va_list(ap);
    va_start(ap, format);
    res = trio_vsnprintf(buffer, max, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return res;
}

int vsnprintf(char *buffer, size_t bufferSize, const char *format, va_list args)
{
    return trio_vsnprintf(buffer, bufferSize, format, args);
}
```

If I delete those lines, the build finishes, but then R output has a three decimal scientific notation exponent instead of a two digit one, (e.g "3.11e-004" instead of "3.11e-04") which causes all kinds of checks to crash. [I have been informed](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-January/070357.html) that this is the standard Windows method, so my deletion of the local R versions almost certainly caused this issue.

My question is, is there any way I can continue to have stdio.h included in the compat.c file, yet have `snpritf` and `vsnprintf` be redefined as the local ones in compat.c?

Thank you.

#### Failed Try 1

I tried adding both straight `#undef` declarations as well as

```
#ifdef snprintf
#undef snprintf
#endif
```

and the corresponding for `vsnprintf` in compat.c, and neither worked. I get the same build error crashing to a halt due to a "redefinition".

#### Failed Try 2

Changing the code in compat.c to:

```
#ifdef snprintf
#undef snprintf
int snprintf(char *buffer, size_t max, const char *format, ...)
{
    int res;
    va_list(ap);
    va_start(ap, format);
    res = trio_vsnprintf(buffer, max, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return res;
}
#endif
```

Allowed the program to compile, but it had the same notation errors, meaning it was functionally equivalent to just deleting those lines.

#### Update per comment request

1. Install some flavor of Mingw-64 and place \bin at head of PATH
2. Install MSYS2: basic install, then add tar, make, zlib, zip, unzip and rsync, and place its bin as second in path
3. Untar R-3.1.2.tar.gz (twice, as the first time returns simlink errors using tar 1.28 from MSYS2. Using the patched tar 1.2.1 from Rtolls does not return errors)
4. Copy Tcl and bitmapdll subdirectories from R64 (Rtools) to proper place
5. Modify MkRules.dist to enforce 64 bit, Windows 64 platform, HTML help, and proper directories for Cairo, Inno, and qpdf, and save it as MkRules.local. For these tests, I am not using an OpenBLAS-based Rblas, not any processor-specific calls to EOPTS other than adding `-pipe` for speed
6. Run `make all`

I've built R a score of times using the binaries in Rtools, including using OpenBLAS (fooling R into thinkinig it's ATLAS). What I have noted, but do not understand, is that `stdio.h` has changed between GCC 4.7 (and thus 4.6) and 4.8 and subsequent. The new verison which contains the line numbers thrown in the error defines `snprintf` and `vsnprintf` directly. The version from 4.6.3 does not. I hae copied the sections below:

stdio.h from GCC 4.6.3 lines 494–514:

```
#if !defined (__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO) || __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO == 0
/* this is here to deal with software defining
 * vsnprintf as _vsnprintf, eg. libxml2.  */
#pragma push_macro("snprintf")
#pragma push_macro("vsnprintf")
# undef snprintf
# undef vsnprintf
  int __cdecl vsnprintf(char * __restrict__ d,size_t n,const char * __restrict__ format,va_list arg)
    __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005 __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;

#ifndef __NO_ISOCEXT
  int __cdecl snprintf(char * __restrict__ s, size_t n, const char * __restrict__  format, ...);
#ifndef __CRT__NO_INLINE
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl vsnprintf(char * __restrict__ d,size_t n,const char * __restrict__ format,va_list arg)
  {
    return _vsnprintf (d, n, format, arg);
  }
#endif /* !__CRT__NO_INLINE */
#endif /* !__NO_ISOCEXT */
#pragma pop_macro ("vsnprintf")
#pragma pop_macro ("snprintf")
#endif
```

stdio.h from GCC 4.9.2 (same as found in 4.8.4) lines 531–565:

```
#if !defined (__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO) || __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO == 0
/* this is here to deal with software defining
 * vsnprintf as _vsnprintf, eg. libxml2.  */
#pragma push_macro("snprintf")
#pragma push_macro("vsnprintf")
# undef snprintf
# undef vsnprintf
  int __cdecl __ms_vsnprintf(char * __restrict__ d,size_t n,const char * __restrict__ format,va_list arg)
    __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_MSVC2005 __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;

  __mingw_ovr
  __MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(3)
  int vsnprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, va_list __local_argv)
  {
    return __ms_vsnprintf (__stream, __n, __format, __local_argv);
  }

  int __cdecl __ms_snprintf(char * __restrict__ s, size_t n, const char * __restrict__  format, ...);

#ifndef __NO_ISOCEXT
__mingw_ovr
__MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(3)
int snprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __ms_vsnprintf (__stream, __n, __format, __local_argv);
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
#endif /* !__NO_ISOCEXT */

#pragma pop_macro ("vsnprintf")
#pragma pop_macro ("snprintf")
#endif
```

Comment: I should be able to solve this but it would help to know exactly how you are building R. Perhaps you could update the post with these details.

Comment: @MikeKinghan, I have updated the post. Please let me know if there is anything else which you think would prove useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: The tarball is a GNU autotooled package. Don't you run `./configure` before `make`?

Comment: [No, because I am in a Windows environment](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html). There are pre-existing makefile.win files, some of which may have to be manually adjusted.

Comment: Before I go further, do you know of this Windows binary distribution of R: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/ Is it unsuitable?

Comment: No, but it is a binary, and as I maintain a package for CRAN, I need to be able to build from source. Also, if you want to use a fast BLAS under windows, there is only one person who has them already compiled, and none for SandyBridge, so I [build them myself](http://www.avrahamadler.com/2013/10/24/an-openblas-based-rblas-for-windows-64-step-by-step/), but this too requires builing from source. I can still build R using the GCC 4.6.3 which is provided in [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). I was hoping to be able to build R using a more recent build of GCC. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have observed, the compile errors in `compat.c` introduced with MinGW GCC 4.7 are caused
by the new inclusion of inline definitions for `vsprintf` and `snprintf` (among others) in `stdio.h`.
This breaks prior code, like `compat.c` that declines the Standard Library's 
formerly external definitions and supplies its own.

You can effect a restoration of the *status quo ante*, per problem function, that is conditional upon the definition of a preprocessor
macro, i.e. only client code for which the macro is suitably defined will compile that function under the *status
quo ante*; other code will compile it under the *status quo*.

To do this you must do a little preprocessor hacking of the problem header `F:/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h`.

Replace the lines [541-560], i.e.:

```
  __mingw_ovr
  __MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(3)
  int vsnprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, va_list __local_argv)
  {
    return __ms_vsnprintf (__stream, __n, __format, __local_argv);
  }

  int __cdecl __ms_snprintf(char * __restrict__ s, size_t n, const char * __restrict__  format, ...);

#ifndef __NO_ISOCEXT
__mingw_ovr
__MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(3)
int snprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __ms_vsnprintf (__stream, __n, __format, __local_argv);
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
```

with:

```
#if NO_INLINE_VSNPRINTF == 0
  __mingw_ovr
  __MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(3)
  int vsnprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, va_list __local_argv)
  {
    return __ms_vsnprintf (__stream, __n, __format, __local_argv);
  }
#else
  extern int vsnprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, va_list __local_argv);
#endif`

  int __cdecl __ms_snprintf(char * __restrict__ s, size_t n, const char * __restrict__  format, ...);

#ifndef __NO_ISOCEXT
#if NO_INLINE_SNPRINTF == 0
__mingw_ovr
__MINGW_ATTRIB_NONNULL(3)
int snprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __ms_vsnprintf (__stream, __n, __format, __local_argv);
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}
#else
extern int snprintf (char * __restrict__ __stream, size_t __n, const char * __restrict__ __format, ...);
#endif
```

(Take care to retain the `#endif`, originally on line 561, immediately following the one that concludes this hack.)

Then, edit `compat.c` and at the top, right *before*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

add the lines:

```
#define NO_INLINE_VSNPRINTF 1
#define NO_INLINE_SNPRINTF 1
```

(These two macros have no conventional meaning. I've just coined them.)

With these changes saved, `compat.c` will compile without errors. At least it does for me.

I haven't gone to the trouble of a full Windows build of R so you may encounter further
breakages. If any are of the same ilk, the pattern of solution is this: If a header
file `header.h` that is `#include`-ed by `foo.c` provides an inline function definition
of the form:

```
__some_decorator
[__maybe_some_more_decorators...]
some_return_type func_name(some arg_type arg0[,some_other_arg_type arg1...])
{
    ....
}
```

then in `header.h` replace it like:

```
#if NO_INLINE_FUNC_NAME == 0
__some_decorator
[__maybe_some_more_decorators...]
some_return_type func_name(some arg_type arg0[,some_other_arg_type arg1...])
{
    ....
}
#else
extern some_return_type func_name(some arg_type arg0[,some_other_arg_type arg1...]);
#endif
```

and in `foo.c`, right before `#include <header.h>` insert:

```
#define NO_INLINE_FUNC_NAME 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It compiled without any crashes. Unfortunately, it compiled as per when I deleted the lines from compat.c. Namely, R output has a three decimal scientific notation exponent (e.g "3.11e-004" instead of "3.11e-04") which causes all kinds of checks to crash.

Comment: It's a linkage problem in that case. Will have to think again.